# changing a sentence into passive and reducing the relative clause

Tags: passive-voice, sentence-choice, reduced-relative-clauses

I wanted to reduce the relative clause of the following sentence or change that into passive structure but unfortunately I couldn't be able to.

> Integrated transport systems that take into consideration local factors are the answer.

However, there are some guesses, I cannot figure out if they are correct or not. But mostly I want to know why it made me confused. Because normally I don't have any problems with this kind of structure.

Here are my goes:

> (changing into passive)
>
> Local factors that are taken into consideration by integrated transport systems are the answer.
>
> (reduction clause)
>
> Taking local factors into consideration, integrated transport systems are the answer.

Comment: *Why* do you want to "change it into passive"? Note that your first attempt to do so changes the meaning. In the original, "the answer" is *integrated transport systems*, but in your revised version it's *local factors*.

Comment: I think any attempt to "passive" the verb ***take*** would inevitably give you an inherently clumsy sentence. ***Local factors  are taken into consideration** by integrated transport systems, which are the answer.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers "*Why do you want to "change it into passive"?*" Because this specific sentence made me think for hours. and I don't know if the agent is *we* like *"If we take local factors into consideration, integrated transport systems are the answer."* or *"integrated transport systems"*

Comment: But ignoring the (optional) clause *that take into consideration local factors*, all you have is the straightforward copula-based assertion *A = B; Integrated transport systems are the answer,* which can't be "passivised" anyway. Forcing a passive construction in this case seems at best pointless.